# Elasticsearch GET just after POST

Tags: elasticsearch, pyes

I'm encountering some issues when performing several `get_or_create` requests to ES.
Elasticsearch seems to take some time after responding to the `POST` to index a document, so much that a `GET` called **just after** returns no results.

This example reproduces the issue:

```bash
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/' -d '{
    "user" : "kimchy",
    "post_date" : "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
    "message" : "trying out Elastic Search"
}' && \
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}' && \
sleep 1 && \
curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/twitter/tweet/_search' -d '{
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}'
```

The `POST` goes well:

```bash
{
    "ok": true,
    "_index": "twitter",
    "_type": "tweet",
    "_id": "yaLwtgSuQcWg5lzgFpuqHQ",
    "_version": 1
}
```

The first `GET` does not match any result:

```bash
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 0,
        "max_score": null,
        "hits": []
    }
}
```

And after a brief pause, shows the result (second `GET`):

```bash
{
    "took": 1,
    "timed_out": false,
    "_shards": {
        "total": 5,
        "successful": 5,
        "failed": 0
    },
    "hits": {
        "total": 1,
        "max_score": 0.30685282,
        "hits": [{
            "_index": "twitter",
            "_type": "tweet",
            "_id": "yaLwtgSuQcWg5lzgFpuqHQ",
            "_score": 0.30685282,
            "_source": {
                "user": "kimchy",
                "post_date": "2009-11-15T14:12:12",
                "message": "trying out Elastic Search"
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Is that behaviour normal ?

Is there a possibility to get the result immediately, even if the response is slower ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your index request cause a new index to be created right? You're not creating it upfront using the create index api if I understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, but that example is based on Elasticsearch's ones on the doc. The fact is that happenned in my environment with previously created indices.  
The two people below have made good answers: using the GET API would be safer for such a case.

Comment: Sure, I hadn't noticed that, the capital http GET method confused me :) as the answers say, use get or explicitly call refresh. Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah this is normal, elastic search by default updates it's indexes once per second.

If you need it to update immediately include refresh=true in the URL when inserting documents

From the documentation:

> **refresh**
>
> To refresh the index immediately after the operation occurs, so that the document appears in search results immediately, the refresh parameter can be set to true. Setting this option to true should ONLY be done after careful thought and verification that it does not lead to poor performance, both from an indexing and a search standpoint. Note, getting a document using the get API is completely realtime.

Comment: Thanks, never heard about this 1s.
As far as I understand the warning, using the `GET` API is way better.
I'll find a way to use this instead of search.

Comment: @Léo Is the get API slower than search ?

Comment: No the get API is at least as fast as search (and probably faster). However it only allows you to fetch documents by id and it doesn't allow you to actually search

Answer (score 4):

If you need realtime access to objects you just indexed you need to use the get API (http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/get/) and not search. Search, as stated here, is not realtime. The get API is. So if you give your object an ID yourself, you can immediately get that object by ID with the get API.

Answer (score 0):

There is also [an optimization](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html#bulk) to turn off search index `refresh_interval` during heavy import (like bulk) and put it back when done.
Then wait/sleep some seconds and it should work.
You may also tune the refresh interval using this (maybe you do not care and want it to refresh only every 15s)