# Mismatch Between Query Result and Index Immediately After Re-Indexing in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, opensearch

I have an index and our post-indexing step, we re-index the index and after, the pipeline (written in Java) uses an aggregation query to fetch product attributes (for example categories and their counts), then we cache these values. I noticed after that the values between index and the cache are not same.

I believe that the problem is we try to fetch categories immediately after re-indexing and index may be not ready to be read (meaning, re-indexing may not be in a completely finished state). Some of the answers includes Refresh API with Java:

```java
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(indexAlias);
indexRequest.setRefreshPolicy(WriteRequest.RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL);
```

but my operation is not actually a IndexRequest, it is SearchRequest since we are passing an aggregation query to the index.

How can I know that my index is fully ready to be read its most up-to-date data?

Answer (score 0):

You can force a refresh request (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-refresh.html) before performing the search.

Also, see the accepted answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18080706/272939. However, in that case, the refresh is performed after indexing a document.